# How can I make two buttons next to each other while having them remain being horizontally centered to the webpage?

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to center and display inline two buttons so that the first button floats left while the other button displays horizontally on the other side of the first button while all of this is being centered to the page.

But for some reason I am stuck and am probably missing something extremely obvious I just cannot figure it out for whatever reason.

So here is what I have:

```css
body {
  background: url("background/background.jpg");
}

.top {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Lemon";
}

.top-rectangle {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 60px;
}

.main-buttons {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.top-main {
  font-family: "american-font";
  color: white;
  font-size: 32pt;
  text-align: center;
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.top-plans {
  font-family: "max-impact";
  color: white;
  font-size: 15pt;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.btnop {
  background: #298371;
  color: white;
  height: 104px;
  width: 308px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btnop:hover {
  background-color: #204e45;
}

#downloadbutton {}

#purchasebutton {}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="top">
    <h1>DELUXEVIEWBOT</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="top-rectangle">

  </div>

  <div class="top-main">
    <p>Deluxe Viewbot is able to increase viewership by more than 1000% your very first time using our service!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="top-plans">
    <p>Plans start at $15 a week and $40 a month!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="main-buttons">

    <form method="get" action="downloads/list.php">

      <button type="submit" class="btnop" style="text-align: center" id="downloadbutton">Download</button>

    </form>

    <form method="get" action="purchase">

      <button type="button" class="btnop" style="text-align: center" id="purchasebutton">Purchase</button>

    </form>

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex;` instead of `display: inline;` on `.main-buttons`
and `justify-content: center;` to center the buttons.

```css
    body {
        background: url("background/background.jpg");
    }

    .top {
        color: black;
        font-family: "Lemon";
    }

    .top-rectangle {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        height: 60px;
    }

    .main-buttons {
      display: flex;
      position: absolute;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      float: left;
    }

    .top-main {
        font-family: "american-font";
        color: white;
        font-size: 32pt;
        text-align: center;
        width: 800px;
        margin: auto;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
    }

    .top-plans {
        font-family: "max-impact";
        color: white;
        font-size: 15pt;
        text-align: center;
        width: 500px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .btnop {
        background: #298371;
        color: white;
        height: 104px;
        width: 308px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-width: 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
        }
        
    .btnop:hover {
        background-color: #204e45;
    }

    #downloadbutton {
        
    }

    #purchasebutton {
        
    }
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="top">
    <h1>DELUXEVIEWBOT</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="top-rectangle">
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="top-main">
    <p>Deluxe Viewbot is able to increase viewership by more than 1000% your very first time using our service!</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="top-plans">
    <p>Plans start at $15 a week and $40 a month!</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="main-buttons">
        
    <form method="get" action="downloads/list.php">
        
    <button type="submit" class="btnop" style="text-align: center" id="downloadbutton">Download</button>
    
    </form>
    
    <form method="get" action="purchase">
        
 <button type="button" class="btnop" style="text-align: center" id="purchasebutton">Purchase</button>
 
 </form>
 
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style="display: inline;">
    <form method="get" action="downloads/list.php">
          <button type="submit" class="btnop" style="text-align: center"  
              id="downloadbutton">Download</button>   
    </form>
    <form method="get" action="purchase">   
    <button type="button" class="btnop" style="text-align: center" 
              id="purchasebutton">Purchase</button>
    </form>
</span>
```

Comment: Please add some explanations with your code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), has all you need to know about flexbox.

```
.main-buttons{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you only need to add this css

```
.main-buttons form {
    display: inline;
}
```